# JMeter script as regression test for REST APIs

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I'm creating a jmeter script to perform regression/smoke test on a set of REST APIs, I have setup response assertions to assert for HTTP response code as well as assert for specific fields in response. While running the tests in GUI mode i'm able to verify the results manually & troubleshoot any problems in View Results Tree & View Results in Table views.

I would like to schedule it to run periodically using Jenkins and needed a way to view the results in Jenkins build on a need basis, especially during test failures.

I have looked in to Jenkins Performance Trend plugin and setup a sample project similar to [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jenkins-and-jmeter). Although it looks like its intended or tailored mainly for performance tests unlike my requirement is to just conduct functional test. Performance Trend plugin still seem to be useful even for functional tests however i couldn't find specific assertion failures messages in it.

Anyone aware of an appropriate plugin or has came across the similar situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option would be using [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper for your JMeter tests, Taurus provides [JUnit XML Reporter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Reporting/#JUnit-XML-Reporter) so your JMeter test results will be plotted in JUnit-compatible format therefore you will be able to use [JUnit Jenkins Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/junit/) or [Test Results Analyzer](https://plugins.jenkins.io/test-results-analyzer/) plugin, the latter can give you output like:

[image]

More information: [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it. I have addressed it by writing a custom XSL to convert JMeter's output file in to custom HTML report (with groovy script) for now & exported it as an build artifact.It worked out well for my situation but Taurus seems interesting choice as well.